# Using ngFor and ngIf codition in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Im was using ngFor and ngIf in a single element, but later tried using ngContainer.

I m trying to hide a row on button click (if Status changes)

```html
<tbody>

   <ng-container *ngFor="let d of pendingData">
      <tr *ngIf="d.status !== 'Issued'">
          <td>{{ d.orderno }} </td>
          <td>{{ d.item }} </td>
          <td> {{ d.emp }} </td>
          <td>{{ d.employee_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.item_name }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.item_qty }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.item_price }}</td>
          <td>{{ d.status }}</td>
          <td><button (click)="onClick()">Issue</button></td>
       </tr>
    </ng-container>

 </tbody>
```

Here i cannot use ngIf in the 1st line to check for status condition cause status is lopped over in ngFor, it will be undefined!

How to i test the condition first and then loop in my above scenario.

Comment: I don't undertsand your problem, could you elaborate please ?

Comment: When the status changes from pending to issued (on button click), its just as simple , i need to hide the row whose status changed

Comment: Well your code should work, you just have to pass d as a parameter in your (click) function

Comment: as per the scnearios code seems fine and also in log it shows status changed: "Status is Pending
 Changed status is Issued", but problem is row is not getting hidden

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, you don't want to show the data which are in issued status already. What you can do is filter it from your component first, before passing to your dom, so you can remove the `ngIf` in the html.

```
let filteredPendingData = pendingData.filter(x => x.status != 'Issued')

<ng-container *ngFor="let d of filteredPendingData">
    <tr>
    </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Correct, only those data whose status changed from Pending to Issued, i need to hide the data for those, and could you please update in my code snippet showing ur code!

Comment: Where is your typescript component? Just remove your `*ngIf` from the html, then put in your typescript component the `filteredPendingData` line of code.

Answer (score -1):

```js
use  <ng-container *ngFor="#d of pendingData">
```

```js
   <tr *ngIf="d.status != 'Issued'">
```

Comment: i get Template parse error: Unexpected token # at column 1 in [#d of pendingData]

Comment: remove # & try d of pendingData